# Toggle into for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I want to ask about multiple toggle into a for loop.
for example, when I click into a div, a toggle menu appear.

this is my code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myObjectString.length; i++) {
var obj = JSON.parse(myObjectString);
document.getElementById("endorsment").innerHTML += "<div id='endor'>\n\
        <div class='endo_"+ obj.Endorsment[i].lang + "' id='endo'>\n\
        <div id='count'>"+ obj.Endorsment[i].ln + "</div>\n\
        <div id='proglang'>"+ obj.Endorsment[i].lang +"</div>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class='contenthover_"+ obj.Endorsment[i].lang +"' id='contenthover'>\n\
        <a class='delete'>\n\
        <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blue-bits/16/symbol-delete-icon.png' />\n\
        </a>\n\
        <span class='devider'>-</span>\n\
        <a class='mybutton'>\n\
        <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/16/comment-icon.png' />\n\
        </a>\n\
        <span class='devider'>-</span>\n\
        <a class='mybutton'>\n\
        <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blue-bits/16/information-icon.png' />\n\
        </a>\n\
      </div>\n\
    </div>";

    $('.endo_'+ obj.Endorsment[i].lang).click(function () {

    //$('#contenthover').toggle();
    alert(obj.Endorsment[i].lang);
});
```

This [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmo1919/2jaLg60o/4/)
Any one can help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is: how can I execute the toggle menu for every DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use your click code inside the for loop. That make no sense.. It will be inserted no. of times inside your document (DOM).

> **Use pseudo query selectors**. That will definitely make your work easier.

```
  $("[class*='endo']").click(function () {    
    //do something here.
    $(this).next().toggle();   
});
```

next() selector selects the next sibling from the DOM. I have made a wrapper class to improve your css. Take a look at the fiddle for better understanding.

### if you remove the wrapper class you may find some problems displaying your "contenthover".

Here's is your **updated fiddle**.

http://jsfiddle.net/xK0nB1n/2jaLg60o/11/

Comment: thanks for your answer, this may help. But what I want to do is execute the toggle for every separated div. This updated fiddle can explain http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmo1919/2jaLg60o/9